# How to make a Navbar that will hide the first session on scroll like this one like one in this site https://preview.colorlib.com/theme/engineers/?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, navbar

I don't know what's correct English I would use to google surely there are jsfiddle or other resources with what I need, I am looking to create a navbar like this one: https://preview.colorlib.com/theme/engineers/

Comment: You will need a piece of javascript that works on the scroll event. Check the position of the scrollbar, once its position is at the top of the page, change the css of the navbar to have position fixed, instead of position relative. Maybe this can help you. https://jsfiddle.net/emanuelzone/rns1pupL/

Comment: Please go read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic This is not a site to outsource your research to, and not one to ask for script/plugin/tutorial recommendations either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this!

**HTML**

```
<div class="navbar">
<a href="#home">Home</a>
<a href="#news">News</a>
<a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>

<div class="main">
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
</div>
```

**css**

```
 /* The navigation bar */
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed; /* Set the navbar to fixed position */
  top: 0; /* Position the navbar at the top of the page */
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
}

/* Links inside the navbar */
.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
     text-decoration: none;
     }

     /* Change background on mouse-over */
     .navbar a:hover {
     background: #ddd;
     color: black;
     }

     /* Main content */
     .main {
     margin-top: 30px; /* Add a top margin to avoid content overlay */
     }
```